# A DSP library(C++) capable of real time processing, Drc and normalisation.

Tags: library, audio, c++, c#, music

I posted this question to stack overflow and was suggested to ask here instead.

I'm currently in the design phase of an audio processing project and I'm trying to pick out a library with the functionality I need as well as good learning resources.

The project I'm making requires me to apply normalisation and dynamic range compression to a recording before or perhaps during playback. I also want to capture background noise with a microphone and adjust the volume of the recording based on this.

The Idea behind the project is to make music more suitable for playing in the background, an 'elevator music converter' if you will.

The language I'm using hasn't been decided but I'm leaning towards C++. I've also had experience with Java and C# and I'd be open to trying Python as well.

From the reading I've done so far I've heard good things about Aquila however it hasn't been updated since 2014 and the documentation is unavailable. I've also been recommended Naudio which is a C# library, this looks good but I imagine the performance won't be as good in real time as C++(I understand that might not be much of an issue on modern hardware).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'd also appreciate being pointed towards any good learning resources for people new to DSP. I'm currently reading the "audio programming book" it has some good stuff on concepts but most of the examples are in C which I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks